# make typescript show type hint for string literal when union with string primitive type

Tags: typescript

Is there an way to make typescript show type hint for the following ?
I am trying to get 'test1' or 'test2' type showing when i am typing 'test' but i failed.

```
type A = "test1" | "test2" | string

// update 1: it does show 'test1' & 'test2' but not in the 'constant' category (e.g. menuItem/spanner/wrench icon ), but in 'string' category (e.g. 'abc' icon )
// <--- doesn't show 'test1' or 'test2' when i am typing 'test'
const a : A = 'test1'
```

In Example 1 , `type A` is wider into string so we lose the type defination of 'test1'/'test2' as string literal

Ideally variable `a` it should still show up 'test1' & 'test2' for autocompletion like `b`variable in Example 2.

### Example 1:

[image: test1 and test2 is suggest as string]

### Example 2:

[image: variable should show autocomplete in this format for test1 and test 2]

Comment: Can you do something like this :`type A = 'test1' | 'test2' | Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` to preserve the type of A?

Comment: ✨magic, it works !! please post as an answer , so i can accept it .
it will even better if u can give a short desciprtion how it work ,but without will still great.

Comment: Hmm, the accepted answer works but not at all for the reason it says; `Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` does not mean "any `string` except `"test1"` or `"test2"`; if it means anything, it means "any `string` without known properties named `test1` or `test2`", which is... werid.   There is an official issue in GitHub about this at [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729), and I've submitted an answer which explains what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical answer to this question is at [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33471](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471).

---

The union of `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) with `string`, such as `"test1" | "test2" | string`, is equivalent to `string`.  There's no value of type `A` which can't be assigned to `string` and vice versa.  Furthermore, such types are eagerly reduced to `string` by the compiler.  This behavior is absolutely correct from the point of view of the type system, but unfortunately it doesn't really do what you want from the point of view of *documentation*.

Ideally you'd like a way to prevent the eager reduction of the union (or at least have the compiler keep track of the pieces of the union for IntelliSense); there is no officially supported way to do this, but there are workarounds:

---

There's a [suggestion in microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729#issuecomment-505826972) to use something like a *branded primitive* (as described in [this TS FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)) for this effect:

```
type OtherString = string & {};
```

Here, `OtherString` is of type `string & {}`; this happens to be equivalent to `string` (the "empty object type" `{}` matches all values except `null` and `undefined`... yes, even primitives like `string`) but the compiler doesn't simplify it, and so it keeps track of the union of literals:

```
type A = "test1" | "test2" | OtherString;
// type A = "test1" | "test2" | OtherString
// not reduced
```

That gives you both the behavior and the hinting you're looking for:

```
function foo(a: A) { }
foo("test1"); // okay
foo("test2"); // okay
foo("test3"); // okay

foo("") //
//   ^ hint here, test1 and test2
```

[image: foo("") hints test1 and test21]

---

Of course, this is just a workaround and there are [some situations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729#issuecomment-706401313) in which `OtherString` might fail to behave the way you want; so be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8sAWEBOBlYSCWA7A5lAvFAM7rZ4BkUA3gL4DcAUKJFAIIFQBEwEJAjJygAfLjxIAmQSLiJUpXIwD0iqM2jtC3XsAHDR2yXpnI0mXA2VQsAe2BQkEACYBXAMZOGDAGbOsr4BjWWFBe1tYAFACGAFxsAJTUUDTeYeFa-JxxdFCW1gDWkSApEenAklk5KvmFxWliwADMmdm5BUW1nJlAA)

Answer (score 3):

`type A = 'test1' | 'test2' | Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>`

type A can be:

- test1
- test2
- any string except test1 and test2

Therefore, 'test1' and 'test2' can be preserved.

---

If you have more string literal types, you can make a new type for it to avoid duplicating `test1`, `test2` ...

```
type fixedString = 'test1' | 'test2' | 'test3' ...
type A = fixedString | Omit<string, fixedString>
```

Comment: This works but not for the reason you are saying.  [The `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) that removes known keys from an object.  `Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` says that you want a type like `string` except it doesn't have *keys* named `test1` or `test2`.  On the face of it this is meaningless; `string` doesn't have keys like that, it kind of has keys like `toUpperCase` and `length`.

Comment: Conceptually you want something like [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion), but `Exclude<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` is just `string`; there are no [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) in TypeScript, and no way to remove a few string literal types from `string`.

Comment: The reason `Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` is because it is similar to making a [branded primitive type as mentioned in this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), and is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#33471](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471) and related issues.  Something like `(string & { tag?: any })` would work just as well as `Omit<string, 'test1' | 'test2'>` and wouldn't be pretending to use negated types.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example shows a type assertion (`as A`), but the picture shows a type annotation: `: A`. I would shy away from type assertions, simply because:

```
type A = 'test1' | 'test2'

const a = 'foo' as A // no error
const aa: A = 'foo' // errors correctly
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=7&pln=4&pc=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkwIGdgEYlQD7NQwCYkAoUgYwHsA7DKAQwWQDMqqcG1YoB6XqDSpQIAJ1FVRlWvQYMAXD0RI2HPgLETR3auIgVgAGxBA)

---

regarding the auto completion, I don't think it can work with type assertions, because you write `as A` after you write `test`, and as you can see, even without having `string` in the union type, you can assert any string `as A`.

if you use a type annotation instead, I have no issues with the auto completion:

[image: type hints showing in typescript playground]
[image: type hints showing in intelliJ idea]

Comment: my issue with `type A = "test1" | "test2" | string`   is that type `A` now only has type defination of 'string' (if u hover above 'A') , 'test1' & test2' string litereal defination is lost which is not what i want.

i will update the question according to ur suggestion to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think this is how union types work. string is wider than any string literal, and every string literal is assignable to string, so it is inferred to string.

Comment: yes, that is a big headache. so i am finding alternative way to workaround for it

Comment: So what issue are you trying to solve with this union type? Every string will be assignable to it… ‍♂️

Comment: updated  the question , sorry for the confusion. there is answer fix all the issue. please check them out

Answer (score -1):

yes, hint showing properly.

[image]

string literal types combine nicely with union types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features together to get enum-like behavior with strings.

```js
type A = "test1" | "test2";


function animate(easing: A) {
  if (easing === "test1") {
      console.log("test1");
    } else if (easing === "test2") {
        console.log("test2");
    } else {
      console.log("ignoring your types though.")
  }
}
animate("test1");
animate("test2");
animate("test3"); // error:Argument of type '"test3"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
```

You can pass any of the two allowed strings, but any other string will give the error.

like this:

[image]

Comment: in my example i included primitive string as my union member so 'test3' should be allow in this case. The end result should show type hint for 'test1' & 'test2'  while allowing other string. Is typescript currently smart enough to to this (or workaround) ?

Comment: i dont think so,  since in ur example `animate` doesn't allow 'test3' as argument.
but i still want to allow other arbitrary string and not losing 'test1' & 'test2' type hint.

Comment: That hint isn't what OP is after. The hint in your image has `abc` next to it which just means this is text is found somewhere else in the document. You would see the menu icon next to it if it were correctly detecting intellisense.